# Waitinga for a message in Play with rabbitMQ

Tags: playframework, rabbitmq

I am using rabbitMQ module to send and receive messages.

Does anyone know how can I send a message and than wait for another message before continuing.

I need to do something like this

```
public static void index(){

    RabbitMQPublisher.publish("queue1", message1);
    ....
    //here i need to wait for message to arrive on queue2  

    render(message2);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the RabbitMQ API but can't you treat this as async IO? Try to read up on Play's Promise object [official docs](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.3/asynchronous).

Something like maybe:

```
Promise<String> delayedResult = veryLongComputation(…);
String result = await(delayedResult);
render(result);
```

Obviously the key will be how you wrap up the RabbitMQ call in a Promise.